# Meteor Collection: find element in array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have no experience with NoSQL. So, I think, if I just try to ask about the code, my question can be incorrect. Instead, let me explain my problem.

Suppose I have e-store. I have catalogs

```
Catalogs = new Mongo.Collection('catalogs);
```

and products in that catalogs

```
Products = new Mongo.Collection('products');
```

Then, people add there orders to temporary collection

```
Order = new Mongo.Collection();
```

Then, people submit their comments, phone, etc and order. I save it to collection Operations:

```
Operations.insert({
  phone: "phone",
  comment: "comment",
  etc: "etc"
  savedOrder: Order //<- Array, right? Or Object will be better?
});
```

Nice, but when i want to get stats by every product, in what Operations product have used. How can I search thru my Operations and find every operation with that product?

Or this way is bad? How real pro's made this in real world?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand it well, here is a sample document as stored in your `Operation` collection:

```
{
  clientRef: "john-001",
  phone: "12345678",
  other: "etc.",
  savedOrder: {
      "someMetadataAboutOrder": "...",
      "lines" : [
          { qty: 1, itemRef: "XYZ001", unitPriceInCts: 1050, desc: "USB Pen Drive 8G" },
          { qty: 1, itemRef: "ABC002", unitPriceInCts: 19995, desc: "Entry level motherboard" },
      ]
  }
},
{
  clientRef: "paul-002",
  phone: null,
  other: "etc.",
  savedOrder: {
      "someMetadataAboutOrder": "...",
      "lines" : [
          { qty: 3, itemRef: "XYZ001", unitPriceInCts: 950, desc: "USB Pen Drive 8G" },
      ]
  }
},
```

Given that, to find *all* operations having item reference `XYZ001` you simply have to query:

```
> db.operations.find({"savedOrder.lines.itemRef":"XYZ001"})
```

This will return the whole document. If instead you are only interested in the client reference (and operation _id), you will [use a projection as an extra argument to `find`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/):

```
> db.operations.find({"savedOrder.lines.itemRef":"XYZ001"}, {"clientRef": 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556f07b5d5f2fb3f94b8c179"), "clientRef" : "john-001" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556f07b5d5f2fb3f94b8c17a"), "clientRef" : "paul-002" }
```

If you need to perform multi-documents (incl. multi-embedded documents) operations, you should take a look at the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/):

For example, to calculate the total of an order:

```
> db.operations.aggregate([
  {$match: { "_id" : ObjectId("556f07b5d5f2fb3f94b8c179") }},
  {$unwind: "$savedOrder.lines" },
  {$group: { _id: "$_id", 
             total: {$sum: {$multiply: ["$savedOrder.lines.qty", 
                                        "$savedOrder.lines.unitPriceInCts"]}}
  }}
])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556f07b5d5f2fb3f94b8c179"), "total" : 21045 }
```

Comment: Touch of Master. Thank you, Sylvain, you way is certainly better. With my little Mongo experience, even simple things puzzles me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm an eternal newbie, but since no answer is posted, I'll give it a try.

First, start by installing [robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) or a similar software, it will allow you to have a look at your collections directly in mongoDB (btw, the default port is 3001)

The way I deal with your kind of problem is by using the `_id` field. It is a field automatically generated by mongoDB, and you can safely use it as an ID for any item in your collections.

Your `catalog` collection should have a string array field called `product` where you find all your products collection items `_id`. Same thing for the operations: if an order is an array of products `_id`, you can do the same and store this array of products `_id` in your savedOrder field. Feel free to add more fields in savedOrder if necessary, e.g. you make an array of objects `products` with additional fields such as `discount`.

Concerning your queries code, I assume you will find all you need on the web as soon as you figure out what your structure is.

For example, if you have a product array in your savedorder array, you can pull it out like that:

```
Operations.find({_id: "your operation ID"},{"savedOrder.products":1)
```

Basically, you ask for all the products `_id` in a specific operation. If you have several savedOrders in only one operation, you can specify too the savedOrder `_id`, if you used the one you had in your local collection.

```
Operations.find({_id: "your_operation_ID", "savedOrder._id": "your_savedOrder_ID"},{"savedOrder.products":1)
```

ps: to bad-ass coders here, if I'm doing it wrong, please tell me.

Comment: Thank you very much, Billy! I do not quite understand how to apply your advice, but you gave me idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer :) Of course, this is not a reveal for real professionals, but is a big step for me. Maybe my experience someone find useful. All magic in using correct mongo operators. Let solve this problem in pseudocode.

We have a structure like this:

```
Operations:
  1. Operation: {
    _id: <- Mongo create this unique for us
    phone: "phone1",
    comment: "comment1",
    savedOrder: [
    {
      _id: <- and again
      productId: <- whe should save our product ID from 'products' 
      name: "Banana",
      quantity: 100
    },
    {
      _id:,
      productId: <- Another ID, that we should save if order 
      name: "apple",
      quantity: 50
    }
    ]
```

And if we want to know, in what Operation user take "banana", we should use mongoDB operator"elemMatch" [in Mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

```
db.getCollection('operations').find({}, {savedOrder: {$elemMatch:{productId: "f5mhs8c2pLnNNiC5v"}}});
```

In simple, we get documents our saved order have products with id that we want to find. I don't know is it the best way, but it works for me :) Thank you!

Comment: From a database perspective, I don't think you need an `_id` in your embedded documents here, as the `productId` *should* be sufficient to differential the various order lines (you don't need two lines for the same `productId`, don't you ?)